# SQL order by hierachical like

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like, sql-order-by

I'm using a Confluence Web page, which display a dropdown list based on a database function. This function have no parameter. This function returns results of a view.

When I begin to entered some text on the textfield, the dropdown list result show data sort.

By instance:

```
text entered : toto
dropdown list list result : 

aaa.toto.aim
aaa.toto.becare
toto
toto.aim
toto.aim.thisis
toto.becare
toto.becare.xxx
```

the view has multiple columns : code_part1, code_part2, code_part3, fullcode (correspond to result display, concatenation of code_part1 + '.' + code_part2 + '.' + code_part3 ) :

```
fullcode            |    code_part1    |     code_part2      | code_part3
aaa.toto.aim        |    aaa           |     toto            | aim
aaa.toto.becare     |    aaa           |     toto            | becare
toto                |    toto          |     (null)          | (null)
toto.aim            |    toto          |     aim             | (null)
toto.aim.thisis     |    toto          |     aim             | thisis
toto.becare         |    toto          |     becare          | (null)
toto.becare.xxx     |    toto          |     becare          | xxx
```

How it's possible update the function with the order by clause depending on what I entered on text box ("toto" here) :

```
toto
toto.aim
toto.aim.thisis
toto.becare
toto.becare.xxx
aaa.toto.aim
aaa.toto.becare
```

Comment: Thanks all for quick feedback. Sorry, maybe I bad explain my issue.
on SQL Server side, we have no idea of filter, and so, we can not really add a order by with a search string, has it doesn't exist yet.
On web server side, the Function is launch (I suppose), and a LIKE statement seems to be apply. So, the result shown is the data on view as we suppose it have been entered on system.

Comment: Confusion is caused by your choice of tags - all of which apply to the dbms. Where do you intend to implement this functionality? In addition, words like "I suppose" indicate confusion on your part as well. Clarify your question with a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve the chance you will get useful sugggestions.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I update my post. I use a confluence web page with a textbox wich display result of a simple function (which return result of view) sorted by first column. But I would like to update function.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of case in order by

```
DECLARE @SearchString CHAR ='toto'
SELECT fullcode 
FROM TABLENAME
ORDER BY CASE WHEN part1 = @SearchString THEN part1  WHEN part2 = @SearchString THEN PART2 ELSE part3 END
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
declare @t table(fullcode varchar(50),code_part1  varchar(50), code_part2  varchar(50), code_part3  varchar(50))
insert INTO @t VALUES
('aaa.toto.aim'        ,'aaa'    ,    'toto' ,              'aim'  )
,('aaa.toto.becare'     ,'aaa'    ,    'toto'  ,          'becare'  )
,('toto'                ,'toto'   ,    null ,         null        )
,('toto.aim'            ,'toto'   ,    'aim'    ,         null    )
,('toto.aim.thisis'     ,'toto'   ,    'aim' ,            'thisis' )
,('toto.becare'         ,'toto'   ,    'becare'   ,      null     )
,('toto.becare.xxx'     ,'toto'   ,    'becare',           'xxx'      )

declare @key varchar(50)='toto'

select *,1 rownum from @t where code_part1=@key
union ALL
select *,2 rownum from @t where code_part2=@key
union ALL
select *,3 rownum from @t where code_part3=@key
```